# Run .Net windows service as administrator on automatic startup

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services, admin

I'm trying to open some .net core apps (with admin rights in app.manifest) as admin from an automatic .Net windows service that runs on startup.

When I simply login and run the service it works fine, but if I set the service to automatically run on startup then it gets the following error on my logs when I restart to test it: "Error: The requested operation requires elevation", this occurs after running

```
myProcess.StartAsActiveUser()
```

as an exception of a try catch.

I added the admin rights on the app.manifest, used the verb runas and turned the UseShellExecute to true... And when i log the

```
principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

at the service startup, it is set to true so the actual user has admin role...

Any Idea of how to get it to work as admin on automatic startup?

Comment: It must not be starting with the admin credential..

Comment: @alexherm yeah, that's the thing. But is there any way to make it work, knowing all the things I have already tried to make it start with admin? Is it possible to start a process as admin without knowing the admin keys or being logged since automatic services run  on startup?